# How to insert value of the checkbox array into the database while the cheekboxs value also have been retrieved from the database?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, checkbox

I am retrieving the result of the query from the database.I have stored id of the record into the checkbox array.
I was able to retrieve the data and store into the checkbox array successfully.now i want to insert the value of the checkbox into different table.In below code i have used a for loop to insert data and implode function to retrive array element but when i run this script it didnt show any error but data was not inserted  into the database.
can anyone please tell me what i am doing wrong? and how can i fix that?

```
<?php

    $conn = mysqli_connect('localhost:3306', 'root', '', 'mydatabase');
    if($conn -> connect_errno){
        die('coudn\'t connect to the database' . mysqli_connect_error());
    }
    else{
        $query = "select * from simple";
        $result = $conn -> query($query);
            echo '<table border="1px"><tr><td>Select</td><td>ID</td><td>Name</td><td>Surname</td></tr>';
            while ($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
                echo '<tr>';
                echo "<td><input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"checkbox[]\" id=\"checkbox[]\"  value=\"".$row['id']."\" /></td>";                   
                echo "<td>{$row['id']}</td> "."<td>{$row['Name']}</td>"."<td>{$row['Surname']}</td>";
                echo '</tr>';
            }
            echo '</table>';
            echo "Fetched data successfully\n";
            $limit = count('$checkbox');
            echo $limit;
            for($i=0;!$limit > 0;$i++,$limit--){
                $res = implode(",", '$checkbox');
                $q1 = 'insert into joint_data values("'.$i.'","'.$res.'")';
                if($conn -> query($query) == TRUE){
                        echo "Data Entered successfully\n";
                    }
                echo $i,$res;
            }
        }
        $result->free();
    mysqli_close($conn);
  ?>
```

Comment: You can do it simply with the POST method by putting the above code inside a form and grab the checkbox value on the action page after the form is submitted

Comment: but for that i have to put the whole code into the html and break it down? is there a any way that i can do it from here??

Comment: Yes for sure if you want the same code to use, you need to break it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$conn = mysqli_connect('localhost:3306', 'root', '', 'mydatabase');
if($conn -> connect_errno){
    die('coudn\'t connect to the database' . mysqli_connect_error());
}
else{
    if(!isset($_GET['checkbox'])){
    $query = "select * from simple";
    $result = $conn -> query($query);
        echo '<form action="" method="get"><table border="1px"><tr><td>Select</td><td>ID</td><td>Name</td><td>Surname</td></tr>';
        while ($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
            echo '<tr>';
            echo "<td><input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"checkbox[]\"  value=\"".$row['id']."\" /></td>";                   
            echo "<td>{$row['id']}</td> "."<td>{$row['Name']}</td>"."<td>{$row['Surname']}</td>";
            echo '</tr>';
        }
        echo '<td><input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit" /></td></table></form>';
        echo "Fetched data successfully\n";
}else{
    $data = $_GET['checkbox'];
        $query = "select * from simple";
        $result = $conn -> query($query);
    $i=1;
        while ($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
            if (in_array($row['id'], $data)) {
        $q1 = 'insert into joint_data values("'.$i++.'","'.$row['id'].'")';
        if($conn -> query($query) == TRUE){
                    echo "Data Entered successfully\n";
                }
                echo $i,$row['id'];
    }
        }
}

$result->free();
mysqli_close($conn);

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This will be code after adding the form

```
<?php
$conn = mysqli_connect('localhost:3306', 'root', '', 'mydatabase');
if($conn -> connect_errno){
    die('coudn\'t connect to the database' . mysqli_connect_error());
}
else
{
    $query = "select * from simple";
    $result = $conn -> query($query);
?>
        <html>
        <body>
        <form name="frmedit" method="post" action="">       
        <table border="1px">
        <tr>
            <td>Select</td>
            <td>ID</td>
            <td>Name</td>
            <td>Surname</td>
        </tr>
        <?php   
        while ($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) { ?>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" id="checkbox[]"  value="<?php echo $row['id'];?>"/>
                </td>                   
                <td><?php echo $row['id'];?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['Name'];?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['Surname'];?></td>
            </tr>
       <?php } ?>
        </form>
        </body>
        </table>
       <?php echo "Fetched data successfully\n";?>
        </html>
       <?php 
        $limit = count($checkbox);
        echo $limit;
        for($i=0;!$limit > 0;$i++,$limit--){
            $res = implode(",", $checkbox);
            $q1 = 'insert into joint_data values("'.$i.'","'.$res.'")';
            if($conn -> query($query) == TRUE)
            {
                echo "Data Entered successfully\n";
            }
            echo $i,$res;
        }
    }
$result->free();
mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```